# Closed form solution for a simple-looking Euclidean geometry problem?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, numerical-methods, euclidean-geometry, closed-form

[image]

The diagram above is distilled from an engineering problem I'm working on. The goal is to compute $R$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$, which are known.

The best I have been able to get so far is an equation that combines all $3$ variables, and is therefore numerically solvable for $R$. However it does not seem that it can be rearranged in closed form to isolate $R$. When I posed it to Mathematica, it returned a hideous monstrosity.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant geometrical approach that I'm missing to isolate $R$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

---

Here is my work so far:

If we knew $\alpha$, the problem would be trivial. Drop the red perpendicular and observe that:
$$
\cos\alpha=\frac{R-r}{R},
$$
which can be rearranged to give:
$$
R = \frac{r}{1-\cos\alpha}.
$$

We do not know $\alpha$ directly, but we know that $\alpha = \theta-\beta$, and we can compute $\beta$ in terms of $R$ and $r$ from the isosceles triangle:
$$
\beta = 2\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)
$$

Now we plug our new expression for $\alpha$ into the above expression for $R$ and we get a nasty-looking equation with $R$ on both sides:
$$
R = \frac{r}{1-\cos\left(\theta - 2\arcsin\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right) \right)}.
$$

---

**Edit: Numerical Solutions**

Here is some data from numerical solutions. I have plotted $R$ vs $r$ with $\theta=\pi/3$ and $R$ vs $\theta$ with $r=1$.

It seems pretty clear that:

- $R$ and $r$ have a directly proportional relationship for fixed $\theta$
- $R$ is inversely proportional to $\theta$ for fixed $R$ (a log-log plot looks straight)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got that,

$0=R^2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-R(\frac{\sqrt{2r}}{2})^2+2\sqrt{R}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2r}}{2})(\frac{r}{2})-(\frac{r}{2})^2$

This is a quartic polynmial from which one could in theory get the solution in a closed form by looking at the roots, I hope you could see if you agree with it.

First you need to notice that $\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R},\ \sin(\frac{\beta}{2})=\frac{r}{2R}$, I add a new image to see if it helps visualize it, from there the rest is just calculations.

[image]

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=-\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})+\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=-\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})+\sqrt{\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})^2\cos(\frac{\beta}{2})^2}$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=-\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})+\sqrt{(1-\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})^2)(1-\sin(\frac{\beta}{2})^2)}$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R})+\sqrt{(1-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2)(1-(\frac{r}{2R})^2)}$

$(\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R}))^2=(1-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2)(1-(\frac{r}{2R})^2)$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R})+(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2(\frac{r}{2R})^2=1+(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2(\frac{r}{2R})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2-(\frac{r}{2R})^2$

$\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R})=1-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2-(\frac{r}{2R})^2$

$0=1-\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2-(\frac{r}{2R})^2+2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R})$

$0=\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})^2-(\frac{r}{2R})^2+2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2R})(\frac{r}{2R})$

$0=R^2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2})^2-(\frac{r}{2})^2+2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2Rr}}{2})(\frac{r}{2})$

$0=R^2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})^2-R(\frac{\sqrt{2r}}{2})^2+2\sqrt{R}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{2r}}{2})(\frac{r}{2})-(\frac{r}{2})^2$

Comment: Remembered this problem, I realize now that another way a bit faster to obtain the same result is by taking $\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{d/2}{R}$ with d the resultant vector of adding the vectors $r$ and $\sqrt{2Rr}$ which by the cosine law has length $d =\sqrt{r^2+(\sqrt{2Rr})^2-2r\sqrt{2Rr}\cos(\pi-\theta)}=\sqrt{r^2+(\sqrt{2Rr})^2+2r\sqrt{2Rr}\cos(\theta)}$, this gives the same result except by a sign in one of the terms that comes from a missing minus sign I forgot in the fifth line

Answer (score 0):

Probably there isn't a nice closed form.

On substituting $z = \frac{r}{2R}$, we get the final expression:
$ \cos (\theta - 2\arcsin(z)) = 1 - 2z $

A query on WolframAlpha, [`solve cos(x - 2arcsin(z)) = 1 - 2z for z`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+cos(x+-+2arcsin(z))+%3D+1+-+2z+for+z), generates an ugly closed form for $z$ .

Answer (score 0):

Except if you want to play with the quartic equation in $\sqrt R$,  numerical methods will work nicely.

With regard to your second plot, if instead of plotting $R(\theta)$, you plot $\frac 1{R(\theta)}$, you will notice a much more "pleasant" curve.

Using Saswat Padhi's answer consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(z)=2 \sin ^{-1}(z)+\cos ^{-1}(1-2 z)-\theta$$
$$f'(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{z-z^2}}$$ which would be used for Newton method.

In order to save iterations, consider the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \theta  & z \\
 0.00000 & 0.00 \\
 0.55107 & 0.05 \\
 0.84384 & 0.10 \\
 1.09654 & 0.15 \\
 1.33001 & 0.20 \\
 1.55256 & 0.25 \\
 1.76866 & 0.30 \\
 1.98125 & 0.35 \\
 2.19247 & 0.40 \\
 2.40416 & 0.45 \\
 2.61799 & 0.50 \\
 2.83569 & 0.55 \\
 3.05916 & 0.60 \\
 3.29066 & 0.65 \\
 3.53311 & 0.70 \\
 3.79052 & 0.75 \\
 4.06889 & 0.80 \\
 4.37816 & 0.85 \\
 4.73763 & 0.90 \\
 5.19704 & 0.95 \\
 6.28319 & 1.00
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, for a given value of $\theta$, a simple table lookup (with or without some interpolation) gives you an estimate of $z$ which will be your initial estimate.

Trying for $\theta=1$, use $z_0=0.15$ and the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 0.150000 \\
 1 & 0.129986 \\
 2 & 0.130308
\end{array}
\right)$$
Trying for $\theta=2$, use $z_0=0.35$ and the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 0.350000 \\
 1 & 0.354432 \\
 2 & 0.354433
\end{array}
\right)$$
Trying for $\theta=3$, use $z_0=0.60$ and the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 0.600000 \\
 1 & 0.586974 \\
 2 & 0.586915
\end{array}
\right)$$

This seems to be quite fast.